# How to make use LSTM's in Flux.jl?

Tags: julia, lstm, flux.jl

I am currently working with some Video data so rather than use a standard feed-forward model, I want to use a Long short-term memory (LSTM) architecture such that the context/memory persists in the reasoning. I looked at the Flux.jl docs but they don't say much about how to actually use the `LSTM` function beyond the input variables such as: `LSTM(in::Integer, out::Integer)`.

How can I make use of the LSTM architecture with flux.jl? What do the `in` and `out` integers represent in this case?